# TestFlight couldn't find the build

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, testing, testflight

Yesterday have I uploaded 2 builds to iOS beta testing platform - **TestFlightApp**. Unfortunately none of the testers, including me, can access those builds. It was working for us fine before.

I receive following message:

> **This device cannot install this build**
>
> TestFlight couldn't find the build you are looking for - perhaps it was removed or you were sent an incorrect url. Check out your dashboard to see all your installable builds

Anyone received similar message ? Is it internal testflight problem, or something is wrong with my build ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Hmm ... I just uploaded a new build, and it seems to work OK now. Will wait till info from test flight with an definite answer.

Comment: Try to contact TestFlight support directly (from their web site or using Twitter), they are quite responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It's happened to me as well, I got the message *This device cannot install this build* and the green button said *Contact Developer*.

After making sure that the user had register his device with test flight and that the device is also on the provisioning profile, I've removed the profile from the Settings app (by going to Settings>General>Profiles) and removed the Safari browsing data (by going to Settings>Safari>Advanced>Testflightapp.com)

Then I went back to the email and clicked on the link to install the app and that worked.

Comment: adding on to the point here, I have read somewhere before on testflightapp that all the previous open versions should be closed in the Safari browser, so that there are no conflicts in their tracking. I have gotten this error before, and I did exactly what g_fred mentioned and it worked. just adding that point of closing all the previous opened testflightapp.com tabs on the Safari should do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem counter-intuitive (it was to me anyway) - even if you provision someone's device, you still have to check off each user on the **permissions** page and click "just update" before they can install an app, EVEN IF you already provisioned their device in the iOS provisioning portal.